# Code to find record with the max length in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a problem where string or binary would be truncated as my input have length more than length in the table. But because my input is a 22k record I cannot find what and where is the record, is there any code in SQL Server to find the record with the max length in a table?

I expect the output is the record which has the max length in the table

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Whre is the `22k input`? how do you `INSERT` into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s simple:

```
Select * from Table where len(somefield) = ( select max(len(somefield)) from Table)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by len(somefield) desc;
```

If you want only one example, remove the `with ties`.

I think this is simpler than using a subquery.